# Pass input parameter as value in stored procedure

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

I am using SQL (plpgsql). I created a stored procedure that takes in a `varchar` value like this 'DUMMYVAR'. I would like to use the input value ('DUMMYVAR') to populate a whole column of the table, **however**, the output error that appears when I try to run it, the stored procedure signals that 'DUMMYVAR' is not a column.

Here's an example stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure(myvar VARCHAR)
AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mytable (var1, var2, dummyvar)
        SELECT 'HELLO', 'WORLD', myvar
        FROM othertable;
END;
$$
```

Assuming there are 5 records in the `othertable` and that `myvar = 'DUMMYVAR'`, what I expect is the following output:

```
var1    var2    dummyvar
HELLO   WORLD   DUMMYVAR
HELLO   WORLD   DUMMYVAR
HELLO   WORLD   DUMMYVAR
HELLO   WORLD   DUMMYVAR
HELLO   WORLD   DUMMYVAR
```

Comment: The `INSERT` statement refers to `dummvar` instead of `dummyvar` -- or is that a Typo? If you run the `INSERT` statement manually, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for me

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE test_source (
      row_id INTEGER IDENTITY 
    , col_1 VARCHAR
);
INSERT INTO test_source (col_1)
VALUES ('hello world')
     , ('hello world')
     , ('hello world')
     , ('hello world')
     , ('hello world')
;
CREATE TEMP TABLE test_target (
      row_id INTEGER 
    , col_1 VARCHAR
    , col_2 VARCHAR
);
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_insert_test( test_value VARCHAR)
AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test_target (row_id, col_1, col_2)
    SELECT *, test_value
    FROM test_source;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
;
CALL sp_insert_test ('test-test-test')
;
SELECT * FROM test_target ORDER BY 1
;
 row_id |    col_1    |     col_2
--------+-------------+----------------
      1 | hello world | test-test-test
      2 | hello world | test-test-test
      3 | hello world | test-test-test
      4 | hello world | test-test-test
      5 | hello world | test-test-test
```